# Prepare a tensorflow dataset with *.jpeg in a directory with corresponding labels in a .csv file

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

Indeed this question is similar to prior but for me attempting prior answers tossed a errors I cannot scale probably due to deprecated functions  and thus update is requested (pleading on my knees really)-- maybe windows 10 is the problem

In the Google tensorflow documentation they trumpet the ease of tensorflow and they of course make it seem easy by having a dataset prepped and ready 
to go such as `mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist`

But for people doing real work with new data they are not going to have data so neatly prepared. Instead they (i.e. me) are going to take many pictures of different similar things (say 64 nuclei of cancer cells from 64 patient cases-- 250 by 250 pixels each with RGB) and they will  store the 64 jpegs in a single directory lets say `C:\\Users\\dalton\\Desktop\\breast\\nuclei\\*.jpg`
There are no other jpgs in the directory other than those of interest

Then in a csv text file (essentially a spreadsheet with one column saved as csv file or could be txt) they record the label corresponding to each picture -- this text file has 64 entries of a 1 or 0 whereby 1= very bad cancer cell and 0= not so bad. Lets say this txt file is located at:
 `C:\\Users\\dalton\\Desktop\\breast\\nuclei\\n_labels.txt`

They (me) will use 32 of the pictures and corresponding labels for train and 32 for test.

So from this basic data of 64 jpegs and 64 labels (as 64 entries in a single text file)how does one get to the same point as given in the loading of an easy example. Or does one need a single `spreadsheet` with the jpeg filenames in one column and the labels in another so as to prepare a list or tuple?

In essence how does

Real world work join final common pathway same as
 `mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist`

I think an answer to this will help many many people besides me. I have tried innumerable examples in `GitHub`, here, and tried R versions and total frustration.

Sincere thanks to an answer.
LD

attempted solutions used examples as per:

https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/datasets

https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f

Comment: Can you possibly remove complaints and leave essence of the question? It is very hard to understand what exactly solution you are looking for and mean when asking?

Comment: Yes, frustration cause me to whine excessively. I have restated.

Comment: Agree was frustrated. How does one prepare a Tensor flow dataset when their entry point is for example 64 jpgs in a single directory on their hardrive and a text file with 64 labels (for me 64 pictures of cancer cells and 64 corresponding labels of estrogen positive vs negative cancer). Other solutions to the same question, as I ask, have not worked for me possibly due to deprecated functions and update would be helpful. Usually in online documentation of how to use tensorflow the entry point is by loading an already prepared dataset (such as dogs and cats). Thank you-- am new to this process.